# Out-of-memory operations in Python datatable package: How to do it?

Tags: python, py-datatable

Python [datatable package](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable) [documentation page](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) states that it supports out-of-memory datasets. I could not find examples of that kind of operations, so I am looking for that.

Thank you

Comment: kindly have a look at [this github issue](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/issues/2860#issuecomment-783646224); you can ask more questions if it is still unclear